# Exclude posts from a specific post_type

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-post-type, taxonomy

I have created a post_type "collection" and all its taxonomy is connected to post_type "product"

so when I do this

```
global $wp;
$posts = get_terms( $wp->query_vars["name"]);
foreach($posts as $post): ?>
<a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $post );?>" rel="bookmark"><?=$post->name . " (".$post->count.")" ?> </a>
<?php endforeach;
```

this will show all the terms in post_type "product" under the taxonomy "style"

but it also shows terms under the post_type "collection" under the taxonomy "style"

How can I exclude showing terms under post_type "collection"

[image]

Comment: I think you are confusing yourself with the way you have named your variables.   Try $terms = get_terms('style');  to get all terms under taxonomy 'style'.   You are fetching terms not posts and post types need not have anything to do with the get_terms other than terms can be assigned to either post_type id the post_type setup allows it.

Comment: Perhaps your question is how to get terms that are assigned to posts in post type product and are not assigned to posts of type collection?

Answer (score 0):

Francis, the code currently fetches 'terms' not posts, which is why you are getting more than you want.      If you looking to fetch posts (not terms) then use https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/.

This example is closest to what you are looking for https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/#comment-2516,   substitute in your post_type and taxonomy.

Answer (score 0):

I Kinda did it like this

```
<?php
$posts = get_terms($wp->query_vars["name"]);
$terms = get_terms($wp->query_vars["name"], array(
    'hide_empty' => 0,
));

foreach( $terms as $term ) :
    wp_reset_query();
    $args = array('post_type' => 'product',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => $wp->query_vars["name"],
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $term->slug          
            ),
        ),
     );
    $posts = new WP_Query($args); 

    if( $posts->have_posts() ) : ?>
        <h3><?php echo $term->name; ?> - <?php echo $posts->post_count ?></h3>
    <?php endif; endforeach; ?>
```

so the **$posts->post_count** did the trick

another is issue is that it hides when its empty, I need to show it all even empty ones